# What is the best option for batch optimising/shrinking PDF files?

Tags: pdf

I have a customer that has been uploading delivery receipts for many years and has 200,000 documents. They vary in size from a few kilobytes to over 5Mb.

They are on a windows 2022 server and I am looking for a solution to batch optimise/shrink the files to ease the burden on the server.

What are the accepted methods for achieving this?
What is everyone using and what should I avoid?

Comment: Please keep in mind that StackOverflow focuses on programming-related problems. Searching for tools is officially off-topic

Comment: You can run `cpdf -squeeze in.pdf -o out.pdf` on them, which is lossless compression. If your large files are large because they contain scanned images, you will need a different solution - one which can reprocess the images.

Comment: Beware, if those PDFs happen to be digitally signed, optimizing them will break those signatures.